# How to export XAML from DataTemplate to another window

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, listbox

Есть некоторая форма, которая хранит в себе Listbox со своим DataTemplate, который представляет некоторые объекты типа object или card в необходимый шаблон.
Нуждаюсь в помощи в поиске решения переноса кода XAML актуального содержания DataTemplate, в другое окно или бинарный файл, чтобы после переноса появилась возможность работы с созданной формой.
Сейчас такой возможности нет, поскольку при обращении к ListBox.Items, объекты представляются типом object, либо Card, с Content == null (Что вполне логично).

Сам XAML выглядит следующим образом:

```
<ListBox x:Name="Test" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionChanged="ProverkaList_OnSelectionChanged">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <materialDesign:Card  UniformCornerRadius="10" Template="{StaticResource Question3}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Что вы пытаетесь сделать?

Comment: Нужно код XAML элемента ListBox (со всем его содержанием) перенести в переменную, считав которую, через код, обращаясь к ListBox, можно было бы управлять его содержимым, например, обратиться к конкретному элементу, который содержится в  ListBox.Item.

Comment: При чем тут XAML? Управляйте привязанными данными, почитайте про INotifyPropertyChanged. Проблема XY, мне кажется. Почитайте здесь десяток-пару постов по меткам WPF+MVVM

Comment: Возможно, вы хотите просто положить `DataTemplate` в глобально доступный `ResourceDictionary` (например, в `App.Resources`), и подключать оттуда во все места, где он нужен.